# Custom content finder tab in adobe cq5

Tags: aem

I have created a custom content finder tab in adobe cq5 referring the page https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CustomCFTab.html.

I have two tabs that displays the contents from the paths as below:

tab 1=a/b and 
tab 2= a/b/c

Now I want tab 1 not to display the content under a/b/c. In other words, tab 1 should exclude a specific sub folder under it.

I played around the url entry but was not successful,

"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/view.json/a/b/"

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK , OOTB Content finder uses `GQL` to fetch the results and display in the CF tab , which is sometimes hard to customize (at least for me !).

You can refer to [ACS Commons](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/contentfinder-querybuilder.html) for a custom version of content finder with `Query Builder queries` (which is much easier to customize than `GQL`).

And for restricting query builder to query for a specific path , you  might refer to this [SOF post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510025/how-do-i-add-a-where-not-to-a-querybuilder-query)

Comment: Thanks Sabya, this was very useful. I have used your suggestions above to come up with a query builder query that works perfectly fine.

Comment: Glad that it helped !

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a way to exclude the path /content/dam/assets from /content/dam.
I added a custom property called cq:damAsset (This is just an example property) to the content and used this to differentiate between the two paths.

With this all the content below the two paths will be as below:

/content/dam-> content under this will have cq:damAsset set to false

/content/dam/asset-> content under this will have cq:damAsset set to true

This way I differentiate the content and query them accordingly.

type=dam:Asset

path=/content/dam

property=jcr:content/cq:damAsset

property.value=false

orderby=@jcr:content/jcr:lastModified

orderby.sort=desc

Again this might not be the best or the efficient solution around. But it definitely served my purpose